# Angular 7 and RxWebValidators library Adding conditionnal validators is setting the add button disabled

Tags: angular, validation, customvalidator, angular7

ihave 3 reactive forms controls:

1. The first one is a `u_id` form control name which it should take the following form: `ADD-DDCDDDDD` and this validation is working properly;
2. The second one is a government issued ID
3. Rge third is the number of this gov ID

I am using `RxWebValidators` library to make conditional validators.

If the user didn't enter his own `u_id`, the save button would be disabled until, at least, he add a gov id type (passport or personal id) and of course the number of this ID should be added too.

And if a user did enter a `u_id`, he can skip the gov ID part and the button will be disabled.

Here is the script:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { RxwebValidators } from "@rxweb/reactive-form-validators"
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, FormControl } from "@angular/forms"
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name = 'Angular';
  userForm: FormGroup

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.userForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      'u_id': new FormControl('', [Validators.minLength(12), RxwebValidators.required({ conditionalExpression: (x) => x.gov_id_type === '' && x.gov_id_number === '' }), RxwebValidators.pattern({ pattern: { 'unid': RegExp('^[0-9A-Z]{3}(-)[0-9]{2}(C)[0-9]{5}$') }, conditionalExpression: (x) => x.u_id !== '' })]),

      'gov_id_type': new FormControl('', RxwebValidators.required({ conditionalExpression: (x) => x.u_id === '' })),

      'gov_id_number': new FormControl('', RxwebValidators.required({ conditionalExpression: (x) => x.gov_id_type !== '' }))
    })
  }

}
```

And the html script:

```
<div>
    <div class="container">
        <main class="col-12">
            <h3 class="bd-title" id="content">Conditional Required Validator
            </h3>
            <br>
<form  [formGroup]="userForm">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" formControlName="u_id" placeholder="UID" class="form-control"  />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<select id="gov_id_type" formControlName="gov_id_type" placeholder="Gov. ID Type" class="form-control">
  <option value="passport">PassPort</option>
  <option value="personal_id">Personal ID</option>
</select>
        <input matInput id="gov_id_number" formControlName="gov_id_number" placeholder="Gov. ID Number" class="form-control"/>

</div>
<button matButton color="warn" [disabled]="!userForm.valid">
        Save Data
</button>
</form></main></div>
```

And a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rxweb-conditional-required-validator-oj8o3u) to check it.

The button is always disabled and the validators are not working

Comment: let me check and update you soon.

Comment: @AjayOjha ok waiting your answer.

Comment: @AjayOjha any news ?

Comment: please check on this url https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rxweb-conditional-required-validator-bqybc7?file=src/app/app.component.ts and confirm it is as expected or not? afterthat I will share you the detail what I have done.

Comment: @AjayOjha Yes that's it. Only one problem is that if I added both 3 fields, the button is disabled. I think I can fix that after you explain it to me.

Comment: my colleague(@IshaniShah) will share you the detail. afterthat any confusion then please let me know.

Comment: @AjayOjha in the answer, it is working in the fiddle but won't on my app, the moment I click inside `u_id` it will turn red and the button will remain disable even if I added gov id with number

Comment: Ok, have you imported the RxReactiveFormsModule in your root module

Comment: Yes, because there is few validators are working properly.

Comment: Can you please come our framework Gitter channel so we can resolve the issue

Comment: This is the url https://gitter.im/rxweb-project/rxweb?source=orgpage

Comment: Have you solved the issue or still you are facing problem?

Comment: @AjayOjha still facing the problem. If I click on the u_id input and focus out it will turn red (which means required even if I added a gov type and number)

Comment: Can you please come on gitter or stackoverflow chatroom

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183679/discussion-between-alim1990-and-ajay-ojha).

Answer (score 1):

@alim1990

In stackblitz working sample having problem of **formcontrol** name naming convention. it must be **u_id** and you mentioned as **un_id** in component.ts file

The below updated code on ngOnInit is

```
ngOnInit() {
this.userForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  'u_id': new FormControl('', [RxwebValidators.required({ conditionalExpression: (x) => x.gov_id_type === '' && x.gov_id_number === '' }), 
  RxwebValidators.pattern({ pattern: { 'unid': RegExp('^[0-9A-Z]{3}(-)[0-9]{2}(C)[0-9]{5}$') }, conditionalExpression: (x) => x.u_id !== '' })]),

  'gov_id_type': new FormControl('', RxwebValidators.required({ conditionalExpression: (x) => x.u_id === '' })),

  'gov_id_number': new FormControl('', RxwebValidators.required({ conditionalExpression: (x) => x.gov_id_type !== '' }))
})
 }

}
```

Please use latest version of **@rxweb/reactive-form-validators** is 1.3.3.

Please check the below link for working solution.
**[conditional required validator](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rxweb-conditional-required-validator-bqybc7?file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

Comment: It is working in the fiddle but won't on my app, the moment I click inside `u_id` it will turn red and the button will remain disable even if I added gov id with number

Comment: are you install latest version of @rxweb/reactive-form-validators ?

Comment: I installed it 2 days ago so it is the latest one I guess.

Comment: can you please check in package.json its version no of @rxweb/reactive-form-validators. please let me know its version no.

Comment: `"@rxweb/reactive-form-validators": "^1.3.3",`

Comment: pl. come on gitter https://gitter.im/rxweb-project/rxweb?utm_source=badge&utm_medium=badge&utm_campaign=pr-badge&utm_content=body_badge otherwise we can discuss on stackoverflow chat room